# How to send packet on tor network to get back to my computer?

Tags: linux, wireshark, tor, packet

Can anyone tell me how to configure system (I think Linux is the best option for this) to be able to send packet by Tor Network back to my own computer? I have to conduct research on how it behaves (I thought about the Wireshark program here to check this packet). I need to have info about how long this packet goes what are packets delays and loss behaviors in Tor. I hope I made myself clear (I am actually a beginner when it comes to Tor, but I've got to do that for college).

Comment: What have you tried this far? Have you been able to produce a working hidden TOR service on your computer which is reachable through TOR network at all? The basic idea is: 1) create a hidden service, 2) access it using normal TOR mechanisms ie. contact .onion address of your service, 3) voilá.

Comment: Sami thanks for your response. I got few questions: Can I create a hidden service from inside network? I am behind my router or do I have to set port forwarding or something like that? And second question do I have to be exit relay or I can create hidden service without any further complication?